# What do "s" and "e" stand for in the Bootstrap 5 spacing utility classes?

Tags: bootstrap-5

Bootstrap 5 documentation for the spacing utility classes states:

> Where sides is one of:
>
> - t - for classes that set `margin-top` or `padding-top`
> - b - for classes that set `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom`
> - s - for classes that set `margin-left` or `padding-left` in LTR, `margin-right` or `padding-right` in RTL
> - e - for classes that set `margin-right` or `padding-right` in LTR, `margin-left` or `padding-left` in RTL

So, for a small bit of left padding, you'll use the class `ps-1` in Bootstrap 5, where it used to be `pl-1` in Bootstrap 4.

I assume they changed this so it would be less confusing for RTL languages, but I can't for the life of me think of what *s* or *e* would stand for. I'm never going to remember "s is left" without actually understanding what metaphor the *s*/*e* stand for.

So, what do *s* and *e* stand for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**S**tart

and

**E**nd

This is so to make using RTL simpler.  In default LTR, Start is Left, and End is Right.

Answer (score 2):

> "I assume they changed this so it would be less confusing for RTL
> languages, but I can't for the life of me think of what s or e would
> stand for. I'm never going to remember "s is left" without actually
> understanding what metaphor the s/e stand for."

As explained in Bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/#approach)...

> "...replace direction properties like left and right in favor **start**
> and **end**. That makes the class names and values appropriate for LTR and
> RTL"